# Error when doing TWRP backup, `recovery.log` shows nonexistent folders

Tags: backup, twrp

The device is Samsung Galaxy A40 with Android 11, rooted with Magisk. I followed the suggestions contained in [TWRP createTarFork() error 255 when backing up data](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/183899/44325).

In the first `recovery.log`, this folder appears: `/data/tombstones/Zde6fQiwYL9jsduZ4MuTrD`; so I deleted it. I relaunched the TWRP backup and, this time, the folder `/data/vendor/M6TyZoh48zRvZQ97YG++eA/ZIaJXVgostztDsV2y4OuqC/GZ3BaraBTRfTO9HxQbjcqA/+TJ7GPVoY48` appears in the relative `recovery.log`, but it is non-existent.

Some idea?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [copy encrypted internal storage to pc ( in twrp mode )](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/221041/copy-encrypted-internal-storage-to-pc-in-twrp-mode)

Comment: maybe, but I don't know

Comment: Some newer devices running TWRP exhibits this problem, honestly you shouldn't use that backup feature, dd is good enough for backing up.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance. What is dd?

Comment: your /data partition is encrypted. no matter what kind of backup you try it's all just garbage (like you see). what you are trying to do is pointless. you can *'adb pull /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/userdata'* but that file is useless (except for restoring to phone as is). if you wanna backup your apps go for Migrate